Terraform create required workflow rules in organization github provider
I'm trying to create an organization ruleset in terraform for my github org.
Following the documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/resources/organization_ruleset#required_workflows
Looks I'm good
    # Fetch the repository ID using the repository name
data "github_repository" "semgrep_repo" {
  full_name = "${var.org_name}/semgrep-caller-${var.org_name}"
}

resource "github_organization_ruleset" "rules_semgrep" {
  count       = var.enable_semgrep ? 1 : 0
  name        = "semgrep_sca_iac"
  target      = "branch"
  enforcement = "evaluate"

  conditions {
    ref_name {
      #Include branches for which this repository rule is applied
      include = ["~DEFAULT_BRANCH"]
      #Exclude branches from this repository rule
      exclude = []
    }
    repository_name {
      #Include repositories for which this repository rule is applied
      include = ["~ALL"]
      #Exclude repositories from this repository rule
      exclude = []
    }
  }

  bypass_actors {
    actor_id    = 1
    actor_type  = "OrganizationAdmin"
    bypass_mode = "always"
  }

  # Set of rules to be applied in this rule
  rules {
    deletion = true
    required_workflows {
      required_workflow {
        repository_id = data.github_repository.semgrep_repo.repo_id
        path = "semgrep-caller-${var.org_name}/.github/workflows/semgrep_caller.yml"
        ref = "main"
      }
    }
  }
}

The plans shows everything will work as expected
# module.github_test_org.github_organization_ruleset.rules_semgrep[0] will be created
  + resource "github_organization_ruleset" "rules_semgrep" {
      + enforcement = "evaluate"
      + etag        = (known after apply)
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + name        = "semgrep_sca_iac"
      + node_id     = (known after apply)
      + ruleset_id  = (known after apply)
      + target      = "branch"

      + bypass_actors {
          + actor_id    = 1
          + actor_type  = "OrganizationAdmin"
          + bypass_mode = "always"
        }

      + conditions {
          + ref_name {
              + exclude = []
              + include = [
                  + "~DEFAULT_BRANCH",
                ]
            }
          + repository_name {
              + exclude   = []
              + include   = [
                  + "~ALL",
                ]
              + protected = false
            }
        }

      + rules {
          + deletion = true

          + required_workflows {
              + required_workflow {
                  + path          = "semgrep-caller-fancom-test-org/.github/workflows/semgrep_caller.yml"
                  + ref           = "main"
                  + repository_id = 832870171
                }
            }
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
╷

But at the moment of applying it doesn't works getting this error
│ Error: POST https://api.github.com/orgs/fancom-test-org/rulesets: 422 Validation Failed [{Resource: Field: Code: Message:Invalid rules: 'Workflows'}]
│ 
│   with module.github_test_org.github_organization_ruleset.rules_semgrep[0],
│   on ../org-settings/main.tf line 154, in resource "github_organization_ruleset" "rules_semgrep":
│  154: resource "github_organization_ruleset" "rules_semgrep" {
│ 


This could be an issue with the plugin provider, SDK, or API since the usage appears correct and the error occurs during the POST to the API. You would need to begin with the plugin issue tracker in that case before moving to the SDK or API issue trackers. If nothing else the plugin should be invalidating the usage prior to an apply if it is incorrect.
